# What are "Enterprise Email Solutions"?

Tags: email

Is anyone familiar with a company called [Coldspark](http://www.coldspark.com/)?  The create software to do "Enterprise Email Solutions".

I don't understand enough about email system administration to know why their product is valuable.  What makes a system an "Enterprise Email" system?

What benefits do Coldspark's solutions provide? Are there any other equivalent vendors that provide similar functionality?

Answer (score 2):

An Enterprise solution is one that costs a lot to obtain and maintain, and does half of what you want with twice the number of servers.  It typically will contain a lot of features that make middle managers happy in their expensively tailored pants, while being a right pain for the people who have to use it and keep it running.

Comment: OK, funny. But -1 for content. There are valid reasons you need enterprise email, like I listed in my answer. It's not just fluff. Although, again, funny. :-)

Comment: And it will be buzzword compliant

Answer (score 1):

I can't commend on ColdSpark, but to me an "enterprise email system" is one that fits an enterprise. Large companies have requirements that are different from mom and pop. For the local small company a POP3 account may cut it. Or perhaps something web based like gmail will be ok. But get to larger organizations where you want to deal with inter-office routing, multiple, controlled entry/exit points to the internet, retention and destruction requirements for emails, eDiscovery, archiving, etc. and you need to step up to something more industrial, or "enterprise" like.

Comment: None of those requirements require you to spend huge chunks of cash on an e-mail server, though.  "Non-Enterprise" mail servers can do all of that without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously something that can handle ["Free bananas in the kitchen!!!"](http://www.metafilter.com/78177/PLEASE-UNSUBSCRIBE-ME-FROM-THIS-LIST#2408665) well has to be considered enterprise, I'd say.